# Checking for a Happy number - else statement not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program which checks if an entered number is a [happy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number).

My code finds each of the numbers after squaring and adding but when it reaches 1, i'd expect it to print "that is a happy number".

I cant see anything wrong with the code but i could be missing something simple.

Here is the code:

```
number = raw_input('What number?')
dictionary = {}
counter = 0
counter_2 = 0 

while counter_2 < 20:
     counter_2 += 1
     if number != 1:        
        for n in str(number):
            n = int(n)**2
            counter += 1 
            dictionary ['key{}'.format(counter)] = n

        added = sum(dictionary.values())
        dictionary = {}
        number = str(added)             
        print number

     else:
        print 'that is a happy number'
```

Comment: number is a string and you are comparing it with a int

Comment: BTW, `not number == 1` is better written as `number != 1`.

Comment: Since `number` is already a string, you don't need to use `str(number)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cant see anything wrong with the code but i could be missing something simple

Yup, something simple `number = raw_input('What number?')` and `number = str(added)` are making `number` a string value, but yet you want to check if it is not the integer value `1`, which is always going to be true, so the "else statement isn't working".

---

Now, I'm not too sure what that dictionary is being used for. Maybe saving the values that have already been calculated to prevent further calculations? That's fine, but here is a solution that already runs fine for the first 1000 happy numbers.

First, two functions for calculating the sum of squares for a number. Note, that converting a number to a string, then iterating over characters and casting back to a integer is unnecessary overhead.

```
square = lambda x: x**2

def square_digits(x):
    square_sum = 0
    while x > 0:
        square_sum += square(x % 10)
        x /= 10
    return square_sum
```

Then a function that checks if a number is a Happy Number with a limit of 20 iterations to prevent an infinite loop.

```
def check_happy(n, limit=20):
    counter = 0
    while n != 1 and counter < limit:
        counter += 1
        n = square_digits(n)
    else:
        return counter != limit
```

And, then simply check your value

```
number = int(raw_input('What number?'))

if check_happy(number):
    print number, 'is a happy number'
```

Sample output.

```
What number? 19
19 is a happy number
```

Comment: Thank you, that works now. I was using a dictionary to allow any number of digits to be used in the inputted number.

Answer (score 0):

**this is my program in find whether a number is happy or not in C++**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i,j,num,temp,sum=0;
    cout<<"Enter number\n";
    cin>>num;
    while (sum != 1 && sum != 4) {
        sum=0;
        while (num > 0) {
            j = num % 10;
            sum += (j * j);
            num /= 10;
        }
        num = sum;
    }
    if (sum == 1) {
        cout<<"Happy Number\n";
    } else {
        cout<<"UnHappy Number\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```